# Input date placeholder dont show in android browser

Tags: android, html, date, input, browser

as the title in my question.

I have this simple script

```
<input type="date" aria-label="Check Out" class="form-control contact-form hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="b-checkout" placeholder="<?php date('d-m-Y') ?>" />
```

In Dekstop version is working well, and than I use mobile view in inspect element also working well.

But when I test with android browser, the placeholder dont show for the first time, but after I chose the date, the place holder will appear.

what I have done is I add this css script

```
input[type="date"]::before { 
     content: attr(placeholder);
     width:100%;
     }
```

But after I test in android browser, the placeholder will be 2 content after I select diferent date, see the image. 
[image]

and than I make some changes in input date

```
<input onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" type="date" type="date" aria-label="Check In" class="form-control date-mobile hidden-lg hidden-md" id="b-checkin2" placeholder="<?php date('d-m-Y') ?>" />
```

In android browser it working well, but in mobile view in inspect element, the place holder dont show after I select the date, see the image
[image]

and make some changes again

```
<input onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onchange="this.placeholder= this.value" type="date" type="date" aria-label="Check In" class="form-control date-mobile hidden-lg hidden-md" id="b-checkin2" placeholder="<?php date('d-m-Y') ?>" />
```

but after I test in android browser is error, see the image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think tht's because you specify that you won't display this element if the size of the screen is small or medium ...

`...hidden-lg hidden-md....`

If you remove it it should display well.